# Visual Studio 2015 Upgrade Removes TFS Connection Information from .sln

Tags: c#, vb.net, tfs, visual-studio-2015

I am converting vs2008 projects to vs2015 via the command line

```
devenv.exe "filepath"  /upgrade
```

When I run this process, the TFS connection information shown below is removed from the .sln file.

```
GlobalSection(TeamFoundationVersionControl) = preSolution
    SccNumberOfProjects = 2
    SccEnterpriseProvider = {4CA58AB2-18FA-4F8D-95D4-32DDF27D184C}
    SccTeamFoundationServer = http://tfsserver:8080/
    SccLocalPath0 = .
    SccProjectUniqueName1 = ProjectName.vbproj
    SccLocalPath1 = .
EndGlobalSection
```

Is there a way to prevent that from happening?

Comment: What happens when you open the upgraded solution in visual studio 2015 after the upgrade?

Comment: Did this only occurs on one project or all of them? There is no other parameters running `devenv /upgrade` command.

Comment: @MrHinsh - the solution was no longer bound to TFS

Comment: @Patrick-MSFT all of them

Comment: @e.gad it's by designed. for vs2015 this connection info is not associate with .sln file any more. They are stored in TeamExplorer.xml file. Detais please see my update answer.

Answer (score 2):

It's by designed.

For VS2008, the TFS connection information are associate with the .sln file.

However, for VS2015 this connection information are not associate with it anymore. It's stored in a TeamExplorer.xml file of VS cache. You can find it in below path: **C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\Team Explorer\TeamExplorer.xml**

```
<!--This configuration file specifies the previously-configured connection details for Team Foundation Server.-->
<server_list>
    <server url="http://xxx:8080/tfs" current="yes">
        <collection guid="145cdf8f-4c6e-47ba-9d9a-4e7328506929" url="http://xxx:8080/tfs/defaultcollection" name="xxxx\DefaultCollection" current="yes" autoload="yes">
... ....
```

This info is useless,so the upgrade remove them. You had to rebound the sln files to TFS manually.

Comment: This got me on the right track when 2017 made my git-based on-premise TFS server disappear, though I needed to update the origin URLs in Git for VS to recognize TFS without having to re-clone.